# Is there a way to install VMware Hardware Version 12 on ESXi 6.5?

Tags: vmware-esxi

At my new job, our server use ESXi 6.5.0 and ESXi 6.0.0 as our Type 1 Hypervisor.
While looking around in vSphere I found a VM at HW Version 12 installed on a host with ESXi 6.5.

As I found [here](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2007240), this version is only suppose to work on VMware personal desktop products Fusion/Workstation/Player.

I was wondering how can that VM work normally as it's not supposed to be supported by the host?

Answer (score 0):

If the VM works there's little reason to upgrade the hardware version.

> A VMware product can power on a virtual machine with a virtual
> hardware version that is lower than what it supports, but
> functionality may be lost. Lost functionality results in menu items
> related to virtual machine operations being grayed out and
> unavailable.

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1003746